# How can I add/change a Maven publishing repository in a Gradle init script

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I'd like an init script that lets me take arbitrary Gradle projects and change the Maven repository location that they publish artifacts to.

Adding a repository is easy enough when you edit the build file directly, just add a `maven{}` block inside `publishing { repositories { } }`. However, trying to do this generically leads to frustration and failure. I tried this:

```
allprojects {
    beforeEvaluate {
        pluginManager.withPlugin("maven-publish") {
            extensions.getByType<PublishingExtension>().publications {
                repositories {
                    maven {
                        url = uri("file:///my/path")
                        name = "myrepo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but, no luck. No such repository appears. I suspect there is a timing issue here: although my code does run, it presumably runs *after* the publishing plugin has created these tasks. What I want to do is register a callback that is run before the publish plugin gets a chance to do that, but I don't know how.